# KAA Endpoint Ownership, can device be owned by many users

Tags: iot, endpoint, kaa, ownership

Can a device be 'owned' by more than one owner? Example, a heater device is owned by different users (from google verifier), controlled by each of their Android phones.

Comment: I ran my own test. Installed Kaa v010.0 on an EC2 instance Ubuntu 16.04, ran multiple android emulations, tried adding a java program running as a device as assisted attachment, it attached on the first android app user, on the second android app user it could not attach. SO I guess the answer is NO, the device can not have more than one owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. In Kaa v0.10.0 The device can only be owned by one user in User Verification and Ownership. Proof is on the comment I added in the question.